# Attributes applied on column "i" in a table in q kdb - Performance

Tags: kdb

When I run below query to get the count of a table, the size and time taken to run the query is almost same. / table t has 97029 records and 124 cols

Q.1. - Does column i in below query uses unique attribute internally to return the output in constant time using has function?

```
\ts select last i from t where date=.z.d-5 / 3j, 1313248j 
/ time taken to run the query and memory used is always same not matter how many times we run same query
```

When I run below query:
For the first time required time and memory is very high but from next run the time and memory required is very less.

Q.2. Does kdb caches the output when we run the query for the first time and show the output from cache from next time?

Q.3 Is there attribute applied on column i while running below query, if so, then which one?

```
\ts select count i from t where date=.z.d-5 / 1512j, 67292448j
\ts select count i from t where date=.z.d-5 / 0j, 2160j
```

When running below query:
Q.4 Is any attribute applied on column i on running below query?

```
\ts count select from t where date=.z.d-5 / 184j, 37292448j 
 /time taken to run the query and memory used is always same not matter how many times we run
```

Q.5 which of the following queries should be used to get the column of tables with very high number of records? Any other query which can be more fast and less memory consuming to get same result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There isn't a `u#` attribute applied to the `i` column, to see this:

```
q)n:100000
q)t:([]a:`u#til n)
q)
q)\t:1000 select count distinct a from t
2
q)\t:1000 select count distinct i from t
536
```

The timing of those queries isn't constant, there are just not enough significant figures to see the variability. Using

```
\ts:100 select last i from t where date=.z.d-5
```

will run the query 100 times and highlight that the timing is not constant.

2. The first query will request more memory be allocated to the q process, which will remain allocated to the process unless garbage collection is called (`.Q.gc[]`). The memory usage stats can be viewed with `.Q.w[]`. For example, in a new session:

```
q).Q.w[]
used| 542704
heap| 67108864
peak| 67108864
wmax| 0
mmap| 0
mphy| 16827965440
syms| 1044
symw| 48993
q)
q)\t b: til 500000000
6569
q)
q).Q.w[]
used| 4295510048
heap| 4362076160
peak| 4362076160
wmax| 0
mmap| 0
mphy| 16827965440
syms| 1044
symw| 48993
q)
q)b:0
q)
q).Q.w[]
used| 542768
heap| 4362076160
peak| 4362076160
wmax| 0
mmap| 0
mphy| 16827965440
syms| 1044
symw| 48993
q)
q)\t b: til 500000000
877
q)
q).Q.w[]
used| 4295510048
heap| 4362076160
peak| 4362076160
wmax| 0
mmap| 0
mphy| 16827965440
syms| 1044
symw| 48993
```

Also, assuming the table in question is partitioned, the query shown will populate `.Q.pn` which can then be used to get the count afterwards, for example

```
q).Q.pn
quotes|
trades|
q)\ts select count i from quotes where date=2014.04.25
0 2656
q).Q.pn
quotes| 85204 100761 81724 88753 115685 125120 121458 97826 99577 82763
trades| ()
```

In more detail, `.Q.ps` does some of the `select` operations under the hood. if you look on the 3rd line:

```
if[$[#c;0;(g:(. a)~,pf)|(. a)~,(#:;`i)];f:!a;j:dt[d]t;...
```

this checks the "a" (`select`) part of the query, and if it is

```
(#:;`i)
```

(which is `count i`) it ends up running `.Q.dt`, which runs `.Q.cn`, which gets the partition counts. So the first time it is running this, it runs `.Q.cn`, getting the count for all partitions. The next time `.Q.cn` is run, it can just look up the values in the dictionary `.Q.pn` which is a lot faster.

3. See above.
4. See above about attributes on `i`. `count` is a separate operation, not part of the query, and wont be affected by attributes on columns, it will see the table as a list.
5. For tables on disk, each column should contain a header where the count of the vector is available at very little expense:

```
q)`:q set til 123
`:q
q)read1 `:q
0xfe200700000000007b000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000002000000000..
q)9#read1 `:q
0xfe200700000000007b
q)`int$last 9#read1 `:q
123i
q)
q)`:q set til 124
`:q
q)9#read1 `:q
0xfe200700000000007c
q)`int$last 9#read1 `:q
124i
```

Still, reading any file usually takes ~1ms at least, so the counts are cached as mentioned above.